# Lightweight C Exception Library

Tags: c, error-handling, exception

```
// names are unique within a function, any valid variable name
// a jump table try, allowing return values to determine the exception thrown(index in a jump table, -1 being success for example)
// you only need to put in what you need, not all exceptions, or total exception count
#define GTRY(name, exc) void* __jt_##name[exc];int __jtix_##name = 0;
// register an exception in the jump table. you don't need to do them all
#define GTEX(name, exception) __jtix_##name;__jt_##name[__jtix_##name++] = &&__tr_##exception##name;
// resets the jump table index to a given value, useful for overwriting exceptions without a new try.
#define GTRST(name, index) __jtix_##name = index;
// a standard try, doesn't actually add anything, but for cleanliness.
#define TRY(name) ;
// throw an exception by name
#define THROW(name, exception) goto __tr_##exception##name;
// throws an exception by jump table index
#define GTHROW(name, exn) goto *__jt_##name[exn];
// begins a catch block
#define CATCH(name, exception) goto __trend_##name;__tr_##exception##name:;
// signifies where the try ends
#define ENDTRY(name) __trend_##name:;
// 'finally' blocks need only be put after an end try.
```

Usage Example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    TRY(magic)
    THROW(magic, EOF)
    CATCH(magic, EOF)
    printf("eof!\n");
    ENDTRY(magic)
    printf("complete\n");
    GTRY(fagic, 2)
    int eof = GTEX(fagic, EOF)
    int rst = GTEX(fagic, RST)
    GTHROW(fagic, rst)
    CATCH(fagic, EOF)
    printf("eof2!\n");
    CATCH(fagic, RST)
    printf("rst\n");
    ENDTRY(fagic);
    //
    TRY(nest) {
        THROW(nest, EOF);
    } CATCH(nest, EOF) {
        printf("eof3!\n");
    }
    ENDTRY(nest)
    printf("complete3\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My purpose was to create a macro-based exception system that can run on embedded devices with ease(magic is done compile-time). There is a potential performance malice if CPUs don't support labels as values and GTRY is used.

Comment: Could you provide some code that really uses this, the example you give will not compile, since there is no function wrapping it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Semantics**
In the languages that implement `try`, `throw` and `catch` the scope is generally larger than a single function. The scope of the exception handling is set by the `try` block and the `catch` block. The C `goto` is limited to the current function, to jump outside of the current function you need to use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`. Your implementation does not seem to use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`.

**Maintainability**
Using a `goto` is generally decreasing maintainability, hiding a `goto` is a bad idea. If I have to maintain code that contains a goto I want to be able to immediately know that there is a goto and I want to be able to find the label immediately as well.

**Performance**
A reason to use `goto` is to [improve performance](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/07/12/computed-goto-for-efficient-dispatch-tables). When goto's actually degrade performance that is another reason not to use them.